# Excel VBA Run-time error -2147217904 (80040e10)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have looked at several posts about this error but I am still puzzled about my particular situation. Here is my code that is causing the error:

```
League = Sheets("GameList").Cells(X, GLeagueCol).Value
            SQLStr = "SELECT LeagueID FROM tblLeagues WHERE League = tblLeagues.LTAB"
            LRec.Open SQLStr, SptConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
            With LRec
                .ActiveConnection = SptConn
                .Source = SQLStr
                .LockType = adLockOptimistic
                .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
                .Open
            End With
```

If I write the code using a table as the source as below it works fine but then I have to go through the recordset until I find a match.

```
LRec.Open "tblLeagues", SptConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: `SQLStr = "SELECT LeagueID FROM tblLeagues WHERE LeagueID = " & League` (assuming it's a numeric value) - Or maybe `SQLStr = "SELECT LeagueID FROM tblLeagues WHERE LTAB = " & League`

Comment: As you can see I have tried several ways to write this LRec.Open statement and left some of the added test code in there. LRec.Open SQLStr, SptConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic was added after I thought that there was something wrong in the With block of code. It was not originally in the code.

Comment: When you get the error, what is the value of `SQLStr`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: LeagueID is numeric in the database but the name of the field is essentially a string. I am trying to extract the ID to build a GRec for the game with the LeagueID instead of the League name. The same is true for Team later in the code. Neither works

Comment: You are not building the string with a variable correctly. You do not want the variable inside of the quotes.

Comment: League which I extract from the worksheet is a string. tblLeagues.LTAB is also a short text in the database. The LeagueID which I am extracting into the recordset is a number in the database.

Comment: Something like this then?

Comment: SQLStr = "SELECT LeagueID FROM tblLeagues WHERE " & League & " = tblLeagues.LTAB"

Comment: No, look at the examples i already posted in my first comment.

Comment: SQLStr = "SELECT LeagueID FROM tblLeagues WHERE LTAB = 'NFL'" - This works now. Thank you so much for hanging in there with me when I didn't get it